# Restricting views of SOME items on a list (sharepoint 2010)

Tags: 2010, list, list-view, view, item-level-permissions

I'm setting up a list which for most items anyone can view.  However I want to have the ability for confidential items to be posted, where only legal, the person creating the item, and anyone he/she lists to be cc'd (a lookup field within the form) can see the item.

Is it possible to have this happen automatically when the person selects a field entitled "Confidential?" as "Yes" and if so, how would I go about doing this?

Alternatively, could I use some sort of organizational structure to say anyone can view their own items and any items of their subordinates in the organization?  Not sure if this is a workaround to the solution, trying to think outside the box a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Put the restricted items in a folder and uninherit the folder to only allow certain people access them. Then make all your views have the "Show all items without folders"